# Connection refused when trying to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis deployed on Openshift

Tags: java, openshift, activemq-artemis

We have an Openshift project ( project1 ) in which we setup an AMQ Artemis broker using the image : amq- amq-broker-7-tech-preview/amq-broker-71-openshif . Being the basic image we don't have any configuration such as SSL or TLS. In order to do the setup we used as example : https://github.com/jboss-container-images/jboss-amq-7-broker-openshift-image/blob/amq71-dev/templates/amq-broker-71-basic.yaml

After the deployment of the image on Openshift we have the following:

- broker-amq-amqp (5672/TCP  5672) No route
- broker-amq-jolokia (8161/TCP  8161) https://broker-amq-jolokia-project1.192.168.99.105.nip.io
- broker-amq-mqtt ( 1883/TCP  1883 ) No route
- broker-amq-stomp ( 61613/TCP  61613 ) No route
- broker-amq-tcp ( 61616/TCP  61616 ) No route

From another Openshift service, in Java we try to connect to the broker but we receive the following error :

```
[org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport] (ActiveMQ Task-1) Failed to connect to [tcp://broker-amq-amqp-project1.192.168.99.105.nip.io:61616?keepAlive=true] after: 230 attempt(s) with Connection refused (Connection refused), continuing to retry.
```

The Java code:

```
user = "example";
password = "example";

String address = "queue/example";

InitialContext context = new InitialContext();

queue = (Queue) context.lookup(address);
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
try (Connection connection = cf.createConnection(user, password);) {
    connection.start();
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
}
```

The JNDI Properties file

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=failover:(tcp://broker-amq-amqp-project1.192.168.99.105.nip.io:61616?keepAlive=true)?randomize=false
queue.queue/example=example/strings
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you're trying to connect to the broker using an OpenShift route, when there is no route defined for the relevant service. You (or the installer) defined a route for Jolokia, but there's no route for the broker.

You won't get a helpful error message here, because *any* hostname that ends with the right domain will get connected to the OpenShift router. However, the router won't know how to process the connection without a valid route, and will probably just return some sort of meaningless error packet to the JMS client.

If you're trying to connect to the broker from another application in the same OpenShift namespace as the broker, you don't need to connect via the router -- just use the service name (presumably `broker-amq-tcp`) and service port explicitly in your JMS set-up.

If you're connecting to the broker from another application in a different OpenShift namespace in the same cluster, you might be able to configure the networking subsystem to allow direct connections to the service across namespaces. This is, unfortunately, a little fiddly to set up after OpenShift is installed.

If you're connecting to the broker from outside an OpenShift namespace, and you can't use services directly, you'll have to connect via a route, and you *must* use an encrypted connection. That's not necessarily for security -- the router will read the SNI information from the SSL header to work out how to route the request.

So you'll need to create a service for the broker's SSL port, create a route for that service, export server certificates from the broker, import those certificates into your client, and configure the client to use an SSL connection URI via the router. Clearly, using the service directly is easier, if you can ;)

All these set-up steps are described in Red Hat's AMQ7-on-OpenShift documentation:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq/7.5/html/deploying_amq_broker_on_openshift/index

although I can't deny that there's an awful lot of information to wade through in that document.

Comment: Or, since this is Red Hat stuff, engage Red Hat Tech Support. I happen to know that all those guys are just sitting on their hands with nothing to do. Sorry, only kidding ;)

Comment: we are trying to connect from the same Openshift project ( from another service in the same Openshift project ) and I assume this is what you mean by same workspace . As you can see in the jndi properties file we are trying to connect using the service name but still receive the error mentioned in the question

Comment: What you have in `jndi.properties` is, I think, `broker-amq-amqp-project1.192.168.99.105.nip.io`. That's not a service name, it's a route hostname. Try  `broker-amq-amqp`. And, yes, "project" is the name that OpenShift uses for what everybody else calls a namespace. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also -- log into the pod where you're running your client, and run `curl broker-amq-amqp:61616`. You won't get a meaningful response because the broker doesn't talk HTTP, but you shouldn't get a "no route to host" or "connection refused", either.

Comment: We tried using the `java.naming.provider.url=failover:(tcp://broker-amq-amqp?keepAlive=true)?randomize=false` but now we receive the same error but with the message : `Failed to connect to [tcp://broker-amq-amqp?keepAlive=true] after: 10 attempt(s)with port out of range:-1, continuing to retry.`

Comment: You haven't specified a port number in your connection URI, so I guess the JMS client runtime defaults to -1.

Comment: Yes, my bad, sorry. After adding the port we receive : `Failed to connect to [tcp://broker-amq-amqp:61616?keepAlive=true] after: 1 attempt(s) with connect timed out, continuing to retry.`

Comment: But do you actually want to use AMQP? Your AMQP port seems to be 5672, but it looks as if your client is set up to use ActiveMQ OpenWire protocol, not AMQP. I _think_ (but would not bet my house) that AMQ 7 will take OpenWire on the `broker-amq-tcp` service on port 61616. You really need to decide what wire protocol you want to use, and make sure both the broker and client are configured appropriately.

Comment: But, really, engage Red Hat support. There's way more complexity here than can be dealt with in SO conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Addition and clarification to answer by Kevin Boone (which is very much correct).

In order for the AMQ broker running inside pod named "broker-amq-tcp" to be reachable from other pods in same cluster:

- start broker inside the container on address 0.0.0.0. This is critical - localhost (loopback; 127.0.0.1) will prevent any connections from outside of the pod from reaching the broker;
- create service (e.g. "broker-amq-tcp-service") for broker-amq-tcp that maps a pod port to container's 61616; e.g. 62626 (or any other);
- connect from other pods using tcp://broker-amq-tcp-service:62626.

The 0.0.0.0 part cost me few days of debugging :)